# sharedpreferences in fragment BottomNavigationView

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement saving data in a fragment, but I can't figure out what the problem is. It seems to have done everything, but still the data is not saved

I have a textview with age and there are two buttons with which you can set the age + and -
There is a save button that doesn't work.

activity main

````
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
 
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.body_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
 
 
        navigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
 
 
                    case R.id.nav_second:
                        fragment = new SecondFragment();
                        break;
 
                    case R.id.nav_third:
                        fragment = new ThirdFragment();
                        break;
                }
 
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.body_container, fragment).commit();
 
                return true;
            }
        });
    }```









FRAGMENT

 public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {
 
    public final String save_key = "save_key";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle SharedPreferences) {
 
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);
 
        TextView age = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.age);
 
 
        Button button_add_age = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_add_age);
        button_add_age.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                    int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()) + 1;
                    age.setText(String.valueOf(age_value));
                }
            }
        });
 
        Button button_remove_age = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_remove_age);
        button_remove_age.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()) > 1) {
                    int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()) - 1;
                    age.setText(String.valueOf(age_value));
                }
            }
        });
 Button saveButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.save_button);
         saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                 editor.putString(save_key, age.getText().toString());
                 editor.apply();
 
             }
         });
 
return v;```
````

Comment: How do you know that it is not saved to prefs? In your code, you never read from prefs.

Comment: after I go to another fragment and then go back to it, the age changes to the default value